# Advanced probability book recommendation

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for an advanced probability book to discover more advanced topics ( central limits for stochastic process, sde, MC...).
I have read a couple of chapters in each of the standard graduate probability books (durrett, williams, kallenberg)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/306458/305862)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend Measure Theory and Probability Theory by Krishna B. Athreya and Soumendra N. Lahiri. If you are interested in Mathematical Statistics, I would recommend the book Mathematical Statistics from Jun Shao, which is very mathematically flavored.

Answer (score 1):

If you like your books to be really advanced, my personal favorite is:

> Probability with a View Towards Statistics by Lucien M. Le Cam

It is quite advanced and you'll find a lot of modern material (sde, CLT for stochastic process, MC, ...) in there. 
For a more classical approach, my favorite is:

> Introduction to Probability and Measure by Billingsley

Comment: The first book was authored by Hoffmann-Jorgensen, not Le Cam.